# phpFlickr Caching to Filesystem or MySQL?

Tags: php, caching, phpflickr

Are you supposed to be able to see distinct filenames via phpFlickr's caching to filesystem or MySQL? I've set the parameters as listed in the readme, but caching does not seem to generate any files or mysql table rows.

I've tried both the filesystem (chmod 777 in cache folder) and mysql method (manually created cache table). Any advice on what's to be done to enable caching on phpFlickr ? http://phpflickr.com/docs/caching/

```
$f = new phpFlickr($key);

$f->enableCache("db", "mysql://user:password@localhost/database");
```

Comment: I am using the filesystem cache and an absolute path. The directory itself has to get the 777 rights. Totally worked for me. Maybe its just another directory, which is out of the base_dir and needs a permission there? Had such a problem before.